# Android Circle progress view show timer inside the circle instead of %

Tags: android, mobile, timer, progress-bar

I'm using this great library: [lzyzsd/CircleProgress](https://github.com/lzyzsd/CircleProgress)

I'm trying to show countdown type timer in the center of circle :  01:30 or 03:50 it's mm:ss but now sure what property to use for it.
I only have option to set prefix and suffix but not the actual text. I have total time for countdown timer in seconds and I can also calculate it to minutes and second, but how do I display it in the center?

If I don't set prefix and suffix it takes 0 by default which I don't want to show.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there seems to be no way to do this directly. Here is what I would do:

```
DonutProgress donutProgress = (DonutProgress) findViewById(R.id.aworkout_dp_totaltime);
donutProgress.setSuffixText(""); //removes the % in the end
donutProgress.setMax(90); //so if the countdown starts from 1min 30 sec
//hides the default text which in this case would be 90 at the start
donutProgress.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000")); //the color is transparent
```

In the xml,

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <com.github.lzyzsd.circleprogress.DonutProgress
                 android:id="@+id/dp"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

           <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/countdownTimerText"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now adjust the size of the donutprogress and the font size of the textview such that the textview fits properly in the centre of the donutprogress. Using the countdown timer set the value of the textview during the onTick Method. And also during the onTick you have to do `donutProgress.setProgress(donutProgress.getProgress + 1);`. Thus your timer would change and the progress would change. Note that the progress starts from 0.